# How do I make my Python program redefine a variable based on a response?

Tags: python, input, customization

So, I've made code for a Choose Your Own Adventure game, or at least the start of one, and I need to know how I can get my code to change a variable's definition based off of an `input()` response. Here's my code:

```
import time
import winsound
PlayerAttributes = None
dream_item = None
print("ADVENTURE")
time.sleep(1)
print("Programmed and Developed by:")
print("Gabe 'GabeCodes' Chavez")
time.sleep(2)
print("We meet our heroes.")
print("Alice: The trained explorer doesn't give up hope.")
print("Although she isn't the strongest, she is the smartest person in the crew.")
print("")
time.sleep(6)
print("Sean: The fun loveable Irishman. He is quick on his feet, but not so much")
print("in the classroom. He has an innate sense of direction.")
print("")
time.sleep(6)
print("Mark: While he is strong, he is very ill-tempered and easy to aggravate.")
print("He tends to sleepwalk and has an inexplicable fear of elephants.")
print("")
time.sleep(6)
print("Amy: Amy is one of the kindest. Not just in the crew, but as an overall person.")
print("She is great with medicine and doesn't fear Mark's anger. They actually make a great balance, 
and a cute couple.")
print("")
time.sleep(6)
print("Choose your Character... ")
PlayerChoice = input()
if PlayerChoice == "Alice" or "alice":
    PlayerAttributes == "smart" and "fast"
    dream_item == "golden totem"
elif PlayerChoice == "Sean" or "sean":
    PlayerAttributes == "clumsy" and "fast"
    dream_item == "little green eyeball"
elif PlayerChoice == "Mark" or "mark":
    PlayerAttributes == "strong" and "smart"
    dream_item == "tiny box"
elif PlayerChoice == "Amy" or "amy":
    PlayerAttributes == "kind" and "healer"
    dream_item == "dark iced coffee"
print("You wake with a start. You see your door, window, and dresser.")
time.sleep(2)
print("'What was I dreaming?' you thought. 'There was a", dream_item, "or something.")
```

Comment: Also, when I run it, the response from the final line is
`'What was I dreaming?' thought. 'There was a None or something'`

Comment: `if PlayerChoice == "Alice" or "alice":` isn't doing what you think it's doing

Comment: Nor is `PlayerAttributes == "smart" and "fast"`

Comment: That's so I can use the character's traits for later.

Comment: I'm storing their traits for later sections.

Comment: but `==` is comparison (not assignment) and it appears you're trying to set it to two values, which you can't do. you need to assign a sequence

Comment: 'm trying to get it to say the `dream_item` instead of `None`.

Comment: @PaulH Do I change the `PlayerAttributes ==` to `PlayerAttributes =`?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare a single value to multiple values, using this kind of syntax will fail:

```py
if my_animal is "cat" or "horse":
    my_operation()
```

This is for several reasons.
The first is that operator precedence interprets the statement as:

```py
if (my_animal is "cat") or "horse":
    my_operation()
```

...and regardless of the truthiness of `(my_animal is "cat")`, `"horse"` by itself (or any string, scalar, non-empty sequence) will be evaluated as `True`.

The second reason this syntax fails is that the `is` operator checks that two object *are the same object in memory*, not equivalent values.

So to correct this you could say:

```py
if my_animal == "cat" or my_animal == "horse":
    my_operation()
```

If you have a lot of animals to check, this becomes cumbersome.
In that case I would recommend:

```py
valid_animals = ["cat", "fish", "horse", "dog"]
if my_animal in valid_animals:
    my_operation()
```

In the case where you're checking against different capitalization, I recommend converting the string to either all upper or lower case:

```py
if character_name.lower() == 'alice':
    character_action()
```

Lastly, where you say things like `PlayerAttributes == "clumsy" and "fast"`, you're way off base there.

First, `==` is comparison, not assignment.

So fix that and open up a python interpreter and evaluate that statement by itself. E.g.,

```py
>>> PlayerAttributes = "clumsy" and "fast"
>>> print(PlayerAttributes)
```

You'll get `True` because like we said above, strings are "truthy" and `True and True` evaluates to `True`.

If you want to assign multiple values to a single variable, you need to use a list, tuple, or some other sequence.

```py
PlayerAttributes = ["clumsy", "fast"] # that's a list
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is a huge help.

Answer (score 0):

To assign a value you need to use a single equal sign "=" and not doubles "==". The doubles are a comparison operator.

A few suggestions:

- Choose a different naming convention for your variables (consult [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names))
- Consider using classes for Player and PlayerAttributes
- Use an "else" in your conditional in case the user enters something unexpected

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I realized that I made the program too complex for both the language and my knowledge in coding, so I simplified it alot. Here's the code:

```
import time
import winsound
gender = ["boy", "girl", "Boy", "Girl"]
##It's simpler now. No set names, rooms, or big choices
print("Are you a boy or girl?")
genderChoice = input("Insert here ->  ")

name = input("What is your name?")
if gender = "boy" or gender = "Boy":
    friend = input("Your roommate walks in looking worried. Her name is...")

elif gender = "girl" or gender = "Girl"
    ##almost the same thing, just with the genders switched
```